# how to find out which sdk version spring-data-couchbase uses internally in spring boor application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring-data-couchbase jar to connect to Couchbase db from spring boot application. Now I want to know which sdk version my spring-data-couchbase using ? whether it's sdk2.x or sdk3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring data couchbase 3.x uses SDK 2.x
spring data couchbase 4.x uses SDK 3.x
spring data couchbase 5.x uses SDK 3.x
```

Also - the command "mvn dependency:tree" will show a dependency tree of your maven project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You're suggesting that I condescendingly assume they don't know what spring data couchbase does?

Comment: You should note that answers do not only just help the OP but also future readers with the same problem. If the OP or any other reader is new to the language it may help them to provide more information on what it does, how it solves the problem and any other information.